# what are the differences between these in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, set

I am a big java fan but i have to work now on C++ for a project. I intended to you a java hashmap kind of feature in c++. After googling i found there exists no hashmap/hashtable in C++ STL library. But i found these data types: map, unordered_map, unorderd_set and hash_map. hash_map is microsoft's specific dll/library and remaining are used under STL. i have to work on IBM XL C/C++ compiler. So i can't use microsoft/boost as my company don't recommend them. All i have to use STL specific. Please, provide some info on these collections. What would be best among these STL specifics if i have to choose hashmap functionality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even a semi-interested second look should have revealed to you that `unordered_map/set` is a hash container. It's part of C++11, and of Boost, and of TR1, and any of those should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read Wikipedia's page on [associative containers in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers_%28C++%29)?

If you want real hash table (with a key providing an hash code, but no order between keys) you could use C++ 2011 [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) template. You'll need a compiler recent enough to be C++11 compatible in that regard.

If you can provide an order on keys, consider also using [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) which is available even in the older C++03 standard.

Comment: What if order doesn't matter?  i mean, all i need is just a key-value pair collection that stores value against key and when needed it should retrieve the value for a given key.

Comment: If you are restricted to C++03 (not C++11, not TR1, not boost) then the simplest way of associate value to a key is to provide some order on that key type and use `std::map`. That order might not "matter" to you but might be easy to provide.

Comment: Then `std::map<std::string,std::string>` should be ok... Since the STL provides an order on `std::string`

Answer (score 4):

`unordered_map` is equivalent to java's `HashMap`, and is a hash map - so it is probably what you are after.

`map` is equivalent to a `TreeMap` in java. It is implemented as a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

`unordered_set` is equivalent to java's `HashSet`. It contains only keys, and not pairs of `(key,value)`